# Baire category related question

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, baire-category

Let $A_n$ be a sequence of closed sets of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $[a,b]\subseteq \cup A_n$, for some 
$a<b
$. Show that at least one of the set $A_n$'s contains an interval.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Baire will give it to you. A complete metric space is not a countable union of  nowhere dense sets.

Comment: This is an almost verbatim application of the Baire category theorem.  Where are you running into trouble in using it?

Comment: Thank you it was my bad, I did terrible mistake considering a  closed set not containing an interval but dense (which was false), I saw my mistake, thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: It has nothing to do with Urysohn's lemma. Use the Baire category theorem. Prove by contradiction. Suppose none of the $A_n$'s contains an interval, i.e., they are closed nowhere dense sets. Use Baire's theorem to show that the union of countably many closed nowhere dense subsets of $\mathbb R$ can't contain an interval. Exactly how was Baire's theorem stated in your class? If it was in terms of open dense sets, well, the complement of a closed nowhere dense set is an open dense set.